# Problems when upload files 2MB or More using php

Tags: php, html

> when Try to upload files less 2mb everything goes fine  when it be more 2Mb I  get "cant not upload a file"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> <title> My website  </title> 
</head> <body bgcolor = "#99CC99">
 <?php $directory = "userfiles/";
 $File_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]; 
 $Type = $_FILES["userfile"]["type"] ;
 $Size = ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"] / 1024); 
 $File_temp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];
 if($Size<= 0){ die('cant not upload a file '); } 
 if (file_exists($directory . " / " . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"])) { die($_FILES["userfile"]["name"] . " already exists. "); }
 if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"])){ if(!move_uploaded_file($File_temp_name,$directory."/".$File_name))
 { die('cant not file'.$File_name); } } else { die('attack on file'); } echo $File_name . " is sucessfully uploaded " . " <br/> " ; 
echo "file size : " .$Size. " <br/> "; 
echo"type :".$Type." <br/> "; ?> </body>
 </html>
```

> when upload file 2mb or more I get "cant not upload a file"

Comment: tried increasing the max upload size in php ini?

Comment: FYI please validate the file type before uploading. Your script allows any type of file to be uploaded and that is dangerous

Comment: What is the value of [`$_FILES["userfile"]["error"]`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: thanks tried increasing the max upload size in php ini  that solve worked for me it was 2mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a problem with the default configuration set in `php.ini` file

> By default, PHP file upload size is set to **maximum 2MB** file in php.ini file

To increase file upload size in PHP, update the [upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) in your php.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 32M
```

You can set the value based on your requirements.

In addition, you can also set the maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded in a single request using the `max_file_uploads`.

```
max_file_uploads = 30
```

After modifying `php.ini` file, make sure you restart your server.

For confirmation, whether your changes are done or not. You can create a test file inside your project folder.

**Create `test.php` and write following code:**

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

**Save the file and open in browser**. It will look something like this:

[image: test.php file]

**Search for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size** in this, it should reflect the new values.

Comment: thanks that's was exactly  MY problem

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you reached `upload_max_filesize` within your PHP config, change the value for higher in your `php.ini` file, and don't forget to restart the Apache server.

TIP: you can check current vaalues and location of the path of used `php.ini` using this PHP script:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
```

[phpinfo() docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

Comment: I really think we should discourage this "How do I do this?" type of questions on SO by experienced members not posting answers that already available in abundance on the same site.